# Using multiple subqueries in oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have these tables with some values.

```
ticket_detail
ticket_header
route_header
route_detail
fleet_header
```

Now I have this question for which I have to write query.

```
Select common ticket numbers 
from ticket header and ticket detail 
where route ids are greater than route_id 
which belong to the place with id ‘04’.
```

*edit*     I tried it using

```
select * from   
   (select ticket_number 
    from ticket_header
    union 
    select ticket_number from ticket_detail)     
where route_id > (select route_id from ticket_detail where id = 4)
```

I tried doing it using sub-queries but it is confusing me. How can we correlate these three queries in a single query ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. For a homework assignment question, you must post code you have tried so far, as evidence of a solid effort. We are happy to assist where you are specifically stuck, but won't provide a full answer.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, [this may be of interest](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated)...

Comment: @Ben fascinating. I was travelling all week and missed that whole discussion

Comment: I'm not sure I'd go as far as to call it fascinating :-).

Comment: heres what I tried ...  "(select ticket_number from ticket_header) union (select ticket_number from ticket_detail) where route_id > (select route_id from ticket_detail where id = 4)"

Comment: Your business rules don't make sense.  Please explain which tables own PLACE_ID and ROUTE_ID

Comment: You need to provide a little more detail about your tables and their columns in order to get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is close, but you need the route_id in the inner query:

```
select *
from (select ticket_number, route_id 
      from ticket_header
      union 
      select ticket_number, route_id
      from ticket_detail
     ) t
where route_id > (select route_id from ticket_detail where id = 4)
```

This assumes that there is only one route_id where id = 4.  You might want `max(route_id)` instead, just to be sure.

Also, as a general rule, you should get used to UNION ALL instead of UNION, since it is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I think the UNION keyword should be INTERSECT instead.

INTERSECT gives you the **common** values. Union gives you all the values in both the result sets without duplicates.

The question still needs some clarifications, but you are on the right path. Your query looks syntactically wrong. Try this and if this does not work, post some sample cases where the output data is not as expected.

```
select ticket_number 
  from ticket_header th
  where th.route_id > (select route_id from ticket_detail where id = 4)
INTERSECT
select ticket_number 
  from ticket_detail td
  where td.route_id > (select route_id from ticket_detail where id = 4)
```